# Placement of the phrase 'throughout history'?

Tags: word-order

Can the phrase 'throughout history' only be found at the beginning or at the end of a sentence? If both are possible, is there a difference in the meaning?

The sentence: Women have been known for being strong throughout history.
    Throughout history, women have been known for being strong.

Is any of the above correct?

Comment: That sentence is fine. Women HAVE BEEN KNOWN, though. The two sentences have different meanings.

Answer (score 3):

Like most phrases, you can work it into sentences wherever you want. The following all mean the same thing.

> **Throughout history** there have been many great women.
>
> There have been many great women **throughout history**.
>
> There have been women **throughout history** who have changed the world.

Comment: Whatever links best to the context around it (history vs. women) should go first, as a matter of emphasis.